# using g to paste matching lines under cursor

Tags: global-command

I wanted to copy a series of lines to a specific place in a file, and these are the options I see, all with `g`, the first two from [the power of g](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g)

1. clear register, copy matching lines to register, paste from register
2. copy to end of file, jump to end of file, yank lines, jump back and paste
3. `:g/pattern/t80` paste to the specific line I'm at, reverse order of lines with `!tac`

All of them are actually a bit convoluted, I think probably 1 is the fastest, as you don't have to check the line number where you want to paste. Is there another way, where I place my cursor to where I want the lines pasted and they get pasted in order?

Comment: What about `:g/pattern/t.`? `.` refers to the current line. There is also `-`, which refers to the line above.

Comment: @husB that would duplicate the lines; during `:global`, `.` is the line on which the command argument to `:global` is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a [mark](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#mark)

The problem with line numbers is that they always stay in the same place, resulting in the reversed ordering you see in your option 3. Marks, on the other hand, can move with the content.

Specifically, (as [Matt points out in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38225/using-g-to-paste-matching-lines-under-cursor/38227?noredirect=1#comment69746_38227)) you can use the automatic `''` mark, which Vim helpfully sets before executing your `:global` command.

```
:g/SEARCH/t''-
```

Comment: This could be improved: `:g/PATTERN/t''-`

Comment: @Matt thanks! I’ll edit

Comment: nice! really nice!